# Стиль как в консоли PowerShell (проблема с цветом)

Tags: c#

**Как сделать стиль консоли, похожим на стиль PowerShell?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пробовал вот так**

```
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ReadLine();
            for (int a = 0; a < 3000000; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Color");
            }
```

**... но получается это**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как-бы, спустя время цвет разворачивается на всё окно, как сделать что бы изначально такой цвет был?**

Comment: Кхм, запустите вашу консольную программу в `PowerShell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После задавания цветов нужно очистить консоль:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

Console.ReadLine();
```